# Override System.Web.Security.Roles functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, overriding

I am using System.Web.Security Membership and Roles, but since my roles are a hierarchy I built my own functions for `IsUserInRole()` and `GetRolesForUser()` so I would like to override these two functions in Roles with my functions.

Can someone show me an example of how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quick search and found [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I've never done it myself but I've had a quick look and it gives you working examples

Comment: I was hoping to be able to just override a couple functions of the regular Role class instead of implementing my own RoleProvider.
Thank you for the time and link though.